# How to mount devtmpfs with mode=777?

Tags: linux, mount, gentoo, device

I'm trying to use gentoo based thin client to access fusion access huawei cloud, with the following issues: CloudClient when redirecting devices to VDI virtual PC, trying to write directly into devices placed inside /dev.(unsuccesful) How do I mount /dev with mode = 777? OS 4.4.26-gentoo with dracut initramfs. I tried to use mount /dev -o remount, mode = 777 with no effect.
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,size=436192k,nr_inodes=109048,mode=755)

Answer (score 0):

`/dev` cannot and must not be mounted with `777` permissions. If one was able to do that, then all system users are effectively root users, and there is no security in the system.

You need to figure out how to fix the CloudClient software.

Comment: Yes, I know that this security issue, but for thin station with ro permissions on NFS resources, that is does not matter. I'm not a developer оf CloudClient software, it's really need root permission's while it redirecting usb devices.

Comment: Are you sure it redirects raw USB devices and not mounted filesystems on the USB devices? And security really DOES matter. When some malicious person hacks into the thin station, it is really easy for him to make it a device to hack / DDoS or otherwise attack any other device in the Internet.

Comment: It's redirecting not storage usb devices, usb webcam's it's main purpose

Comment: Then your approach is completely wrong here. You need to use the webcam's API to get data from it to a filesystem, and then share the files from the filesystem.